# MYSQL Select between start end date date format d-m-Y

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, select

If i do this in MYSQL it works:

```
    SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE
reservationStartDate >= '2018-01-01' 
AND
reservationEndDate <= '2018-02-16'
AND
reservationSpace = 'kantoor-1'
```

So i want to make a function like this:

```
        public function checkReservations($startdate, $enddate, $workspace, $bind="") {
            //SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE reservationStartDate >= '2018-01-19' AND reservationEndDate <= '2018-02-01' AND reservationSpace = 'kantoor-1';
            // Date format = 2018-12-31
    $sql = "
            SELECT * FROM DATABASENAME.reservations
            WHERE
            reservationStartDate >= '".$startdate."' 
            AND
            reservationEndDate <= '".$enddate."'
            AND
            reservationSpace = '".$workspace."'
            "
            ;               
    $this->run($sql,$bind);
}
```

And in php i use:

```
$test2 = $db->checkReservations('2018-01-01', '2018-02-16', 'kantoor-1');

echo '<pre>'.print_r($test2,true).'</pre>';
```

It show's nothing... Im almost there btw i have change the format of the date to Y-m-d

Comment: Try: between condition mysql.

Comment: What is the datatype of reservationStartDate

Comment: Please check type of "reservationStartDate" and "reservationEndDate" columns in SQL database

Comment: @DeadManAlive, how dare you?!? I wrote my answer in 2 minutes after the question, the above links were added AFTER my answer...

Comment: @user2342558 so whats the matter?? and what you mean by **posts above were added**. The links which i set to duplicates are older than months/years. Not in `2 minutes` :P

Comment: the 'above links'

Comment: THIS question (this page) is posted 2 minutes after my answer. -_-

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) MySQL function:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE reservationStartDate 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('22-01-2018', '%d-%m-%Y') 
        AND STR_TO_DATE('03-02-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

**[`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)** and **[`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)**

`BETWEEN` is the better form of `reservationStartDate >= '22-01-2018' AND reservationStartDate <= '03-02-2018'` (also in terms of speed) but it your case it works only with `STR_TO_DATE` converting the 'd-m-Y' string to a real date format to let MySQL to handle it.

**[`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html) type field**

The best thing you can do is to use a `DATE` type field to store a date, so you don't need `STR_TO_DATE` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to select rows from a `MySQL database` table in a date range, you need to use a command like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date_column >= '2014-01-01' AND date_column <= '2015-01-01';
```

You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert your strings to `MySQL` date values :

```
SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE reservationStartDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('22-01-2018', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('03-02-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

However, you would be wise to convert the column to the `DATE data type` instead of using strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE reservationStartDate >= '22-01-2018' 
AND reservationEndDate<= '03-02-2018'
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE reservationStartDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2017', '%d-%m-%Y') AND reservationEndDate STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') This gives an error. I want to get START and END date

Comment: @Gurdt please post your mysql error.